# Quicksort string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, quicksort

I'm writing a quicksort algorithm to sort an array of strings.

The problem is that my array with the data seem to be overwritten with something right after i allocate the right and left quicksort arrays, because i print the array and its all there, but after i use malloc to allocate the others arrays, i print it again and i'm missing some elements.

Here's the output:

```
Pivot: 2
Emma, Olivia, Victoria, Gwyneth, Chloe, Hayley, Scarlett,
Emma, Olivia, Victoria, Gwyneth, , , ,
```

Anyone knows whats happening? What am missing?

```
char **concatenate(char **array1, int n1, char *pivot, char **array2, int n2, int len){
int i=0, j=0;
int elements = n1 + n2 + 1;

// alocating array
char **concat = (char**) malloc(sizeof(*concat) * elements);
concat[0] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*concat) * elements * len);
for(i=1; i<elements; i++)
    concat[i] = &(concat[0][i*len]);

// concatenating 
for(i=0; i<n1; i++)
    concat[i] = array1[i];
concat[i++] = pivot;
for(j=0; j<n2; j++)
    concat[i++] = array2[j];

// returning
return concat;
}

char **quicksort(char **array, int elements, int len){
// array is already sorted
if(elements < 2)
    return array;

int pivot;
int i=0, l=0, r=0;

// selecting the pivot (median)
if(elements % 2 == 0)
    pivot = ((elements + 1) / 2) -1;
else
    pivot = (elements / 2) -1;

//REMOVE
printf("Pivot: %d\n", pivot);
for(i=0; i<elements; i++)
    printf("%s, ", array[i]);
printf("\n");

// alocating arrays
char **left = (char**) malloc(sizeof(*left) * pivot);
left[0] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*left) * pivot * len);
for(i=1; i<pivot; i++)
    left[i] = &(left[0][i*len]);

char **rigth = (char**) malloc(sizeof(*rigth) * pivot);
rigth[0] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*rigth) * pivot * len);
for(i=1; i<pivot; i++)
    rigth[i] = &(rigth[0][i*len]);

//REMOVE
for(i=0; i<elements; i++)
    printf("%s, ", array[i]);
printf("\n");

//quicksorting
for(i=0; i<elements; i++){
    if(array[i] == array[pivot])
        continue;

    int comp = strcmp(array[i], array[pivot]);

    //REMOVE
    printf("%d: strcmp %s, %s is %d\n", i, array[i], array[pivot], comp);

    if(comp < pivot)
        left[l++] = array[i];
    else
        rigth[r++] = array[i];
}

//REMOVE
printf("concatenate(");
for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    printf("%s ", left[i]);
printf("|%s| ", array[pivot]);
for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    printf("%s ", rigth[i]);
printf(")\n");

// recursion and return
return concatenate(quicksort(left, l, len), l, array[pivot], quicksort(rigth, r, len), r, len);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int i, j, aux;                  

char **teste = (char**) malloc(sizeof(*teste) * 7);
teste[0] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*teste) * 7 * 128);
for(i=1; i<7; i++)
    teste[i] = &(teste[0][i*128]);
teste[0] = "Emma";
teste[1] = "Olivia";
teste[2] = "Victoria";
teste[3] = "Gwyneth";
teste[4] = "Chloe";
teste[5] = "Hayley";
teste[6] = "Scarlett";

quicksort(teste, 7, 128);

printf("AFTER\n");
for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    printf("%s, ", teste[i]);
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're allocating an array sized for `int`s but you're storing pointers in it. Use `char **concat = malloc(sizeof(*concat) * elements);` instead. You'll have to make similar changes for all of the malloc calls. (You also don't need to allocate memory for Quick Sort. One of its strengths is that it can sort in place.)

Comment: Compile with warnings turned on ( -Wall in gcc ) and fix the warnings before running your code.

Comment: @pburka i've changed all the malloc call but i'm still missing some elements on the same spot.

Comment: @bfagundes Do you need to write your own quicksort, or can you use the standard library function `qsort()`?

Comment: @H2CO3 i'm writting my own because i'm going to make a parallel version with MPI afterwards and i thought it would be better.

Comment: Your memory structure is very confusing. You allocate memory for `teste[0]` and then you overwrite that pointer with the literal string `"Emma"`. You should consider redesigning your algorithm to avoid dynamic allocation all together. It's unnecessary, you're leaking memory, and it's probably connected to your problem.

Comment: There is zero reason to allocate for quicksort, and in fact the function can easily suffice in your case with a simple interface of `quicksort(char *arr[], size_t len)`, using pointer-math for the subsequence invocations. In fact, you would probably be shocked at how short the implementation would be.

Comment: Note that your mallocs are still incorrect, but you can nearly always get away with what you've done. `concat[0] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*concat) * elements * len);` should be `concat[0] = malloc(sizeof(*concat[0]) * elements * len);`.

Comment: @pburka Now its working! I don't know why but after i changed the malloc calls i'm not missing the elements. The sorting needs more work, though. hehe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is zero reason to allocate for quicksort, and in fact the function can easily suffice in your case with a simple interface of quicksort(char *arr[], unsigned int len), using pointer-math for the subsequence invocations.

Provide a swap algorithm for exchanging pointers:

```
void swap_str_ptrs(char const **arg1, char const **arg2)
{
    const char *tmp = *arg1;
    *arg1 = *arg2;
    *arg2 = tmp;
}
```

Then the algorithm is:

```
void quicksort_strs(char const *args[], unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int i, pvt=0;

    if (len <= 1)
        return;

    // swap a randomly selected value to the last node
    swap_str_ptrs(args+((unsigned int)rand() % len), args+len-1);

    // reset the pivot index to zero, then scan
    for (i=0;i<len-1;++i)
    {
        if (strcmp(args[i], args[len-1]) < 0)
            swap_str_ptrs(args+i, args+pvt++);
    }

    // move the pivot value into its place
    swap_str_ptrs(args+pvt, args+len-1);

    // and invoke on the subsequences. does NOT include the pivot-slot
    quicksort_strs(args, pvt++);
    quicksort_strs(args+pvt, len - pvt);
}
```

Thats *everything*. including the partitioning.

**How It Works**

There are two general recursive quicksort algorithms: the *squeeze*, and the *sweep*. This is the *sweep* algorithm. We march up the sequence, swapping any element "less" than than pivot value (which is swapped to the end of the sequence before the loop starts) to a target slot, the index of which is initially the beginning of the sequence and increases with each swap operation. When the "sweep" is finished, the `pvt` index is where the pivot *value* belongs, as everything below that slot is "less" than the that value. So one more swap is made to put the pivot value into position. After that we have two partitions, which are recursed. It is *vital* that the slot we just identified as the pivot location is *not* included in either of those partitions. It is the only value we *know* is in its final resting place.

**Test Harnass**

Including the above code, we test this with a basic set of strings purposely out of order:

```
void print_list(char const *args[], unsigned len)
{
    unsigned i=0;
    for (;i<len;++i)
        puts(args[i]);
}

int main()
{
    char const *args[] =
    {
        "this", "is", "a", "test", "of", "quicksort", "with", "strings"
    };

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    quicksort_strs(args, sizeof(args)/sizeof(*args));
    print_list(args, sizeof(args)/sizeof(*args));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
a
is
of
quicksort
strings
test
this
with
```

---

**Non-recursive implementation**

It should be noted that the above algorithm lends itself *beautifully* to a non-recursive implementation.  A local dynamic stack is used for holding pairs of data: an pointer and a length. Optimized to *not* push trivial segments (segments of length 1 or 0) on to the stack, one implementation would like like this:

```
void quicksort_strs(char const *args[], unsigned int len)
{
    // holds our non-recursive stack of segments
    struct segment
    {
        char const **arr;
        unsigned int len;
        struct segment* next;
    } *stack = NULL;

    stack = malloc(sizeof(*stack));
    stack->arr = args;
    stack->len = len;
    stack->next = NULL;

    while (stack != NULL)
    {
        unsigned int i, pvt=0;
        struct segment *tmp = stack;
        stack = stack->next;

        // pull values and delete segment record
        args = tmp->arr;
        len = tmp->len;
        free(tmp);

        // nothing to unary segments
        if (len <= 1)
            continue;

        // swap a randomly selected value to the last node
        swap_str_ptrs(args+((unsigned int)rand() % len), args+len-1);

        // reset the pivot index to zero, then scan
        for (i=0;i<len-1;++i)
        {
            if (strcmp(args[i], args[len-1]) < 0)
                swap_str_ptrs(args+i, args+pvt++);
        }

        // move the pivot value into its place
        swap_str_ptrs(args+pvt, args+len-1);

        // lhs segment push
        if (pvt > 1)
        {
            tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
            tmp->arr = args;
            tmp->len = pvt;
            tmp->next = stack;
            stack = tmp;
        }

        // rhs segment push
        if ((len - ++pvt) > 1)
        {
            tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
            tmp->arr = args+pvt;
            tmp->len = len-pvt;
            tmp->next = stack;
            stack = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously having a canned node-stack implementation would shorten this up considerably, but the idea should be readily apparent. A `realloc()` schema for holding nodes on the *end* of the "stack" rather than the beginning would be equally interesting, as it would eliminate the need to `next` pointer management, replaced with a `top` index instead.

Anyway, good luck, and I hope it helps.